# Invoke signalr hub method from one app and receive in javascript in another app

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm very curious and very much in need of some pointers.

Basically I have a web application that invokes a hub method in .NET (c#)

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://domain/signalr");
 IHubProxy applicationHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ApplicationHub");
 hubConnection.Start().Wait();
 applicationHubProxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", appKey).Wait();
```

And ideally if a client (another application hosted else where) has a connection to the hub then receive the message in js.

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.url = "http://domain/signalr";

// Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
var applicationHub = connection.createHubProxy('ApplicationHub');

//mock is just a dynamic type that recieves the message in the join group hub method
applicationHub.on('mock', function (msg)
{
  alert(msg);
});
```

Please note that I'm already using Cors, and singalr is working fine with Tests. As I begin with the production code, I'm hoping I could get a better understanding of how the above is going to work.

So just to reiterate, how do I receive a response in JavaScript that is sent from another app in c#?

Any help greatly appreciated,

Comment: The server needs to broadcast it to the clients. On a separate note - don't use `.Wait()` use `await` - while it does not matter too much in case of Console apps you will dead lock yourself once you start non-console apps.

Comment: Cheers for the advice on ".Wait()" So I have .Net Client that connects and invokes a hub method "JoinGroup". but on a differerent app I want to be able to receive a message that notifies the app that a client has connected.(I have js that connects to the hub bit it does not receive the message) any ideas?

Comment: I think you could use OnConnected event on the server to broadcast a message to the clients. The other client should get the message if it is connected to the same SignalR server and the same hub if the message was sent to him (e.g. if you are sending to a group a client has to be in this group). Before doing groups you might try broadcasting the message to `Clients.All` to have one variable to investigate fewer.

Comment: @Pawel thanks for the quick response. Yes it works, sending to all. Just not with groups. Debugging signalr is a nightmare. Just need to figure out why it wont broadcast a message to users in group. thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it means that the client you are trying to send the message to is not in the group you target with your message (check for typos ;))

Comment: @Pawel I thought it might be a typo, but it cant be the case because if i invoke the join method in js, all works fine. It just wont work in C#, Name of the group is exactly the same. It's starting frustrate me haha.